# Php Dom brother/sister node - proper way

Tags: php, xml, dom

So I was playing with domDocs in php and I was going through structure of many nodes. When the script finds `APP_ID` it was looking for, he then need to return his brother value, `APP_USER`. 
I found no solution on here, only XPath and jQuery that I find '*avoiding*' of how it meant to be used.

It's very simple
Before you call foreach, put one iterating variable e.g. `$i` which will then 'call' the brother's value.

```
$apps = $root->getElementByTagName( 'APP_ID' );
$i=0
foreach( $apps as $app ) {
    if( $app->item(0)->nodeValue == CONSTANT-ID ) { // just condition
        $user = $root->getElementsByTagName( "APP_USER" );
        echo $user->item($i)->nodeValue;
        // this $i means it returns brother's value
    }
    $i++;
}
```

what do you think?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: the term you are looking for is "sibling"

Comment: Can you give an example document that shows the structure of the document, i.e. the actual relation between those two elements?

Comment: I think your code does not work. Please provide a working example when you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `$app`, you can use [`parentNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.parentnode) to go up one level and then iterate over [`childNodes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) to find the sibling `APP_USER`:

```
if( $app->nodeValue == CONSTANT-ID ) { // just condition
    foreach ($app->parentNode->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->localName == 'APP_USER') {
            echo $child->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the more "proper" way would be to use `nextSibling`. Apart from that, I'd appreciate if you could move your answer to the linked dupe and cv this one.

Comment: @Gordon: The linked question is IMHO not a dupe -- if nothing else, the OP here asks for an approach without XPath -- and it's also **a mess**. I sincerely fail to see how doing this will help the site. Additionally, `nextSibling` alone won't work in the general case (you 'd need a loop, and another one for `previousSibling`, at which point it gets tedious).

Comment: It helps the site to collect the different possible approaches to one problem under one question instead of spreading one here and one there where no one will find them. The linked is the older one, so it should go there. You can pretty much use nextSibling in a while loop. Apart from that, we do not know whether APP_USER is a sibling at all or the OP is merely using the word brother node incorrectly.

Comment: @Gordon: Sorry, I don't agree with that reasoning (why on earth should we care which is the *older* one? is age a metric of usefulness, or of *anything* for that matter?). I also don't see how to adapt this answer so that it's relevant to the other question. But most of all, I don't want to argue. :) If the OP is using the word brother incorrectly, well I did my best to help given the circumstances. That's good enough for me.

Comment: In order to create relevant canonicals, adding to existing questions is the better option because you are adding to existing value instead of silo-ing it on a new one that will likely be deleted anyway. And it's also less risky to close and delete newer ones, because they are less likely to have been used in closing, e.g. less risk of creating broken links in the "duplicate of foo" block.

Comment: I do recognize the validity of that argument, but let's not elevate it to axiomatic status. In other words: IMHO this specific proposed dupe *sucks*. I wouldn't have any objection if it were more relevant and the answers there more useful. As it is, in my view it offers nothing to SO (it's also debatable if this one does, but that's another story).

Comment: Well, there is probably better dupes in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sibling+php+dom. Pick one. The main issue was likely the OP not knowing the term sibling.

Comment: @Gordon: Assuming I picked one right now, what would I do with it? It would have been fruitful to have this discussion before closing.

Comment: true, I picked the first one that seemed appropriate to me. But that's why I keep encouraging people to use the search function *before* answering ;)